# Filtering problem with v-if and v-for in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

I'm in trouble with a computed property in Vue.js, used in a v-if. Can't find my way to solve or refactor this. Some directions would be welcomed.

**The context:** I display various elements from an array (produced with Axios) and in each div of the template, I get the value for one element of this array. It works without any problem.

**The issue:** Some elements of the array are empty and for these ones, I'd like either display nothing or, in some case, display an alternative div with generic content. And that's where I have a problem. I use a computed property to check is the element of the array is null or not. Then I use this computed in a v-if.

**The code:** (it's the case with alternate content)

```
methods: {
    getItem() {
          axios.get('http://4.4.4.4/api/table?&filter[where][name]=' + this.txtInput).then(response => {
            this.items = response.data
          })
    this.txtInput=''
    } 
}
```

The computed property is inspired by the [second answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933606/v-for-and-v-if-not-working-together-in-vue-js)):

```
computed: {
 nonNullArticle: function() {
      return this.items.filter(i => i.article !== null)
    }    
}
```

And in the template:

```
<div v-if="nonNullArticle">
    <div v-for="item in nonNullArticle">{{ item.article }}</div>
</div>

<div v-else>
    <p>alternate content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the original order and show different contents:

```
<div v-for="item in this.items">
    <div v-if="item">{{ item.article }}</div>
    <div v-else>alternate content</div>
</div>
```

If you want to show "not null" items before, and, at the end, the "null" items you should create two different computed properties, one for "not null" elements and one for "null" elements, and then:

```
<div v-for="item in nonNullArticle">{{ item.article }}</div>
<div v-for="item in nullArticle">alternate content</div>
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But there's a catch: for the case where i needed the alternative div, I need more than one element. So I put everything in a template tag as per the doc. But it's not completely removed from the Dom and I can't find what I do wrong.

Comment: @Plouf what do you mean for "it's not completely removed from the Dom"?

Comment: There is an empty rendering of some of the elements that should dissapear. `<template v-for="item in nonNullItems">
  <read-more more-str="read more" :text="item.article" link="https://www.exemple.com" less-str="less" :max-chars="400"></read-more>
</template>

<template v-for="item in noItems">
  <p>alternate content</p>
</template>  `

Comment: @Plouf if you see `<!---->` it's normal (this means that something is hidden by v-if). If you see some html element with no content within... I don't know, I should see full code

Comment: I made a basic test to figure out what happens. The problem seems to come from the computed property that commands the alternate display. Here are the two properties. My test works correctly with the first but I get both displays with the second: `nonNullArticle: function() {
  return this.items.filter((item) => {
      return item.article !== null;
      });
},
noArticle: function() {
            return this.items.filter((item) => {
                return item.article == '';
                });
          }  ` Maybe it's not the correct way to check for null?

Comment: @Plouf try to use the same value for conditions (example: `item.article !== null` on first and `item.article === null` on second) based on the kind of value you have for null/not null

Comment: Finally solved the issue: the value I got from the DB through the API for this field was an empty string, not a null. I corrected this and now the alternative display works correctly. But notwithstanding that mistake of mine, your answer got me running, thks again!

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `filter` always returns an array, even if it's empty, which is truthy. So instead of checking `<div v-if="nonNullArticle">` you should do `<div v-if="nonNullArticle.length">`