# Filter array if it has a specific key value pair

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

In Vue-JS, I am using a **computed property** and want to filter an array on the basis of key-value pair, this is my array which contains objects as (in `data() {}`):

```
menu_content: [
  {
    title: "Dashboard",
    icon: "dashboard",
    group: false,
  },
  {
    title: "User",
    icon: "account_circle",
    group: true,
    sub_menu_items: [
      {
        title: "Edit",
        sub_group: true,
        sub_group_items: [
          {
            title: "Admin",
            icon: "verified_user",
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Here in this array I have `group` property which can be `false` or `true`, so I have written some code to filter on the basis of this *key-value* pair as (in `computed: {}`):

```
haveSubGroup() {
  this.menu_content.forEach(item => {
    if (item.group)
      return item.sub_menu_items.filter(sub_item => sub_item.sub_group == true);
  });
}
```

If I `console.log()` the above `return` statement, it gives me an **observable**, and if I use `{{ haveSubGroup }}` in the `<template>` I don't see anything!

Comment: Did you know you're basically breaking the loop from the handler of function `forEach`, rather than returning `true/false`?

Comment: Try using triple ```===``` --> ```sub_item.sub_group === true```

Comment: What's the purpose of `haveSubGroup`? this function should return boolean or an array of objects?

Comment: Actually, I want to use v-if and v-for on the same element but *Vue* doesn't allow that then I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48934453/9713525), I want to filter `sub_menu_items` on the basis of `sub_group`. If `sub_group` true then `haveSubGroup` will return those array elements only so that I can access `sub_group_items` in the `<template>`.

Comment: I see a couple of issues. What exactly are you trying to obtain? All sub items where `sub_group === true`?

Comment: ...yea, it's not clear what you're trying to filter on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know you are breaking the loop by using that `return` statement in the `forEach` loop, I have following solution for you, hope it will help!

```
haveSubGroup() {
  let temp = [];
  this.menu_content.forEach(item => {
    if (item.group)
      temp.push(item.sub_menu_items.filter(sub_item => sub_item.sub_group == true));
  });
  return temp[0];
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
haveSubGroup() {
  this.menu_content.forEach(item => {
    return item.group && item.sub_menu_items.some(sub_item => sub_item.sub_group);
  });
}
```

Comment: No, it returns true only.

Comment: @IsaacSuarez you are breaking the loop by using `return` statement.