# Displaying(adding, editing) and Deleting list items in multiple columns in Vue.js without v-if and v-for

Tags: list, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I am beginner in Vue.js. I want to add new items in list, but these ***items need to be displayed in separate divs according to their "category" property***. Also, ***every item has option to be edited (haven't made that yet) or deleted***. I have read that it is not recommended to use `v-if` inside `v-for`, so inspired by [second answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933606/v-for-and-v-if-not-working-together-in-vue-js) I used **Computed Properties** to do that. I needed to add index for every list item, because I haven't found any way to delete list item in Vue.js without index. The problem is that we iterate over two lists from computed properties and basically we have repeating indexes (check out print of list items in my code and you will understand) so it **deletes items from wrong category**. **This problem would make editing item names harder, too.** 
 I was thinking of way to solve this, but **I would have to use v-for and v-if together which is not recommended**.
Also, this is not very good solution for me, because ***I would probably need to generate these divs dynamically from given list of categories (there could be a lot of them)***, and I don't know how would I be able to generate computed properties dynamically for each category. For this I would need to use `v-if` inside `v-for`, which is not recommended.


***So basically I have two problems:***
**1. Deleting items from wrong category** 
**2. Dynamically generating divs for each category if I keep using this method with computed properties.** 

Here is my code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5f78xr9q/5/) 
Do you have any advice or solutions? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` in the `v-for` has nothing to do with that of the object in the `amenities` array.

Since you don't want to make one loop for both categories, I can this solution:

A better approach would be to autogenerate a unique `id` for each object on addition, and then deleting according to it:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      Amenity: {
        name: '',
        category: ''
      },
      amenities: [],
      nextId:0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    familyCategory: function () {
        return this.amenities.filter(i => i.category === 'family')
    },
    facilitiesCategory: function () {
        return this.amenities.filter(i => i.category === 'facilities')
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addAmenity: function(e) {
      this.amenities.push({
        id: this.nextId,
        name: this.Amenity.name,
        category: this.Amenity.category
      });
      this.Amenity = {
        name: '',
        category: 'family'
      };
      this.nextId = this.nextId+1;
    },
    
   removeElement : function (id) {
      console.log(id);
      this.amenities=this.amenities.filter(e => e.id!=id);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <br /> Amenity name:
  <input type="text" v-model="Amenity.name" placeholder="Amenity name">
  <label for="category">Category:</label>
  <select id="cetegory" v-model="Amenity.category">
    <option value="family">Family</option>
    <option value="facilities" >Facilities</option>
  </select>
  
  
  <input type="button" @click="addAmenity" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">

  <div>
  <h3>Family</h3>
    <ol>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in familyCategory">
        {{ index }} - {{ item.name }}
        <button>
          Edit
        </button>
        <button v-on:click="removeElement(item.id)">
           Delete
        </button>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h3>Facilities</h3>
    <ol>
     <li v-for="(item, index) in facilitiesCategory">
        {{ index }} - {{ item.name }}
        <button>
          Edit
        </button>
        <button v-on:click="removeElement(item.id)">
           Delete
        </button>
        </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer Majed! This definitely solves the problem with deleting. If you have idea for dynamically generating divs, without need for making computed property for each category, feel free to write it.

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as the solution. Why don't you make seperate arrays for each category? This way you would have two ``v-for`` (one for each) and the index would be the location of the object in the array.

Comment: I marked the answer as the solution. I will try that but generally I would like to automate that and make dynamic as much code as possible. Thank you Majed!