# Disable specific combo box items in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a `<select>` that is populated from a JSON list called **Ingredients** with data like (ID, DESC, Vegan) so items are like (1, chocolate, N), (2, Sunflower, Y). The interested party is shifting towards a vegan menu only but still wants to see non vegan ingredients in old recipes.
I need to *make the non vegan ingredients still visible but disabled for old non vegan recipes*, newer ones would only show vegan ingredients.

My question is how to apply an `if` on the loop in the for

`IF (VEGAN === 'N') the option will be disabled`

```
<select class="form-control">
        <option v-for="ing in Ingredients" v-bind:value="ing.ID">{{ing.DESC}}
        </option>
</select>
```

Where and how to add a `v-if`?

Comment: you could use the :disabled attribute. :disabled="ing.VEGAN === 'N'". Or is this not what you want?

Comment: If you are just not wanting to show it, then why not use a computed property to filter your ingredients first

Comment: @Pete Please post an answer and if it works I'll accept it.

Comment: @fOURP It is not working neither inside select nor option.

Comment: Have a look at this - is probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933606/v-for-and-v-if-not-working-together-in-vue-js

Comment: @Pete That will hide the non vegan for older recipes, an empty combo would show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood You correctly take a look at following snippet (like commented use `disabled` property):

```js
const { ref, computed } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const ingredients = ref([{ID:1, DESC:'chocolate', vegan:false}, {ID:2, DESC:'Sunflower', vegan:true}, {ID:3, DESC:'chocolate', vegan:false}, {ID:4, DESC:'Sunflower', vegan:true}])
    const onlyVegan = ref(false)
    const handleClick = () => {
      onlyVegan.value = !onlyVegan.value
    };
    return {
      ingredients,
      handleClick,
      onlyVegan
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option v-for="ing in ingredients" :disabled="onlyVegan && ing.vegan" v-bind:value="ing.ID">{{ing.DESC}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <button @click="handleClick">toggle vegan</button>
</div>
```